# Way to delete/erase duplicate elements from std::vector while maintaining order?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Is there a way to delete duplicate elements from vector container containing string elements while maintaining order.

Till now I have used set method, but it doesn't retain the order.

I don't know how to use remove_if with respect to this problem.

Comment: If the container has an order (That is, its elements are sortered) duplicates are contiguous. So, where is the problem? If you remove a duplicate, the order is not modified.

Comment: @Manu343726: "has an order" does not mean "is sorted".

Comment: Do you want to only remove consecutive repeated values (like the Unix command `uniq`), or also later reprtitions? That is, if your original vector looks like `{ "apples", "apples", "oranges", "apples", "grapes" }`, should the result be `{ "apples", "oranges", "apples", "grapes" }` or `{ "apples", "oranges", "grapes" }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a temporary container:

```
std::vector< int >::iterator i , j ;
std::set< int > t_set;
for( i = v.begin() , j = v.begin() ; i != v.end() ; ++i )
    if( t_set.insert( *i ).second) 
        *j++ = *i ;
v.erase( j , v.end() );
```

Using `std::remove_if`, I can think of this:

```
std::set<int> t_set;
std::vector<int> res; //Resultant vector

remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(res), 
    [&t_set](int x){ 
        return !t_set.insert(x).second; 
    } );
```

Comment: +1, I've posted almost identical solution it seams, but much later than you did.   This is fastest (O(n log n)) of doing this.

Comment: If the objects are expensive to copy (the question speaks about strings; it doesn't say how long those are), you could also store the iterators into the original vector in the set, using a custom comparison functor which dereferences the iterators. Also, you might use `swap` instead of assignment if those objects have cheap `swap`. In C++11, move assignment would be the obvious choice.

Comment: It is giving this error while using std::remove_if - expected primary-expression before '[' token

Comment: Temporary container solution worked expeditiously.

Comment: @MayankLal Did you use `-std=c++0x` option for compilation of `std::remove_if` version ?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: Not quite. It's O(n log n), but it's not really fast. See my comment on the question, it has a link to an answer I wrote that's faster.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You answer to similar question is identical to first POW's version (and mine too), as far as I can see. Can you tell me what difference is?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: Huh? It's completely different. Your answers use `std::set`, mine uses `std::sort`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ops, sorry, was looking in the wrong place. I like sorted arrays too. But, I can see two cases where your code will be slower.  First if, most of elements are duplicates and will be removed. And second case, when elements are very big.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: Yes, it will be asymptotically slower if most elements are duplicates, but I'm not sure if it will be empirically slower. But I don't see why the element size matters at all there, could you explain?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Look at these [benchmarks](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/).  In these test we can take `std::list` as aproximation for `std::map`. Test "random_insert - 4096 byte" will explain what I am talking about.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: Something tells me you're taking *guesses* at what I've written instead of actually *reading* it. My code **never** copies the elements into a `vector` (or any other container), so the size of each element is totally irrelevant. Did you actually *read* my code?

Comment: @P0W Any way around using -std=c++0x, I am unable to find that compilation option in codeblocks.

Comment: @MayankLal that's compiler flag, sorry I'm familiar with CodeBlocks, check the Properties/Options for compiler in the Idle.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an empty array, then iterate over the original vector and only copy over the first instance of each item in the vector.  You could keep track of whether or not you've seen an item yet in the vector by adding it to a set and checking for an items presence in the set before adding it to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
 std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8 };
 // 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8

 for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();i++)
 {
     for(size_t j=0;j<v.size();j++)
     {
         if(v[i] == v[j] && i != j)
         {
              v.erase(v.begin()+j);
              j--; // Fix for certain datasets ie: 
         }         //                             1 2 1 1
     }   
 }

 // Produces:
 // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: In order to make sure you don't first occurrence of a value, make sure to pass the current iterator + 1 as the first argument for std::remove.

Comment: Thanks. This gave correct solution.

Comment: Wait, you changed it.  Why'd you add 1 to `j`, in the `erase` statement?

Comment: Yeah, it worked but I kept 'j' instead of 1.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I fixed the issue. It works now. Remove the old comments mate :)

Comment: This is O(N^3) - way too slow.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = std::unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

This iterator will point to the element next to the last element. You may not use this iterator if not required.

See [THIS](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) for further reference

EDIT:

As I thought that the vector would be sorted, the new solution could be:

```
    vector<int> vec= {5,1,2,3,5,4,2,1,1,4,3,2,4,5,2,1,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,2,3,5,2,1,3};
    set<int> s; 
    vector<int>::iterator vecIter=vec.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator vecIterCopy;
    for(;vecIter!=vec.end(); vecIter++) 
    {
        if(s.find(*vecIter)==s.end()) 
        {
            s.insert(*vecIter);
            *vecIterCopy++ = *vecIter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That requires the vector to be sorted (or at least, for all duplicates to be contiguous). You can't maintain the order of an arbitrary vector.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I interpreted the order as sorted.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorting takes nlogn, which will give the same complexity as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

O(n*log(n)) solution:

```
vector<string> V={"aa","bb","aa","cc","cc"};
set<string> S; 

auto i=V.begin();
auto j=i;

for(; i!=V.end(); ++i) {
    if(S.insert(*i).second  &&  i!=j++) 
        *j = std::move(*i);
}

V.erase(j,V.end());
```

Also modified POW's version with `std::remove_copy_if`. But here without extraneous temporary:

```
set<string> S;
V.erase(
    copy_if(
        make_move_iterator(V.begin()),
        make_move_iterator(V.end()),
        V.begin(),
        [&](const string& x){ return S.insert(x).second;}
    ),
    V.end()
);
```